# Click to populate text

Tags: javascript, html, button, populate

I have been using the following:

```
<form onsubmit="javascript: alert('sending...'); return false;">
<input type="text" id="screen" />
<div id="keypad">
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <br />
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <br />
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <br />
    <button>0</button>
</div>
</form>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
    var screen  = document.getElementById('screen'),
        keypad  = document.getElementById('keypad'),
        buttons = keypad.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            screen.value = screen.value + this.innerHTML;
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/nTzY4/3/)

I wanted to make the text box a lot bigger, how would I do that? Want to have the height and length much bigger.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

add a class like so and make css to change your element

```
.bigger
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

<input class="bigger" type="text" id="screen" />
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a noob, just trying to create something for work. where in the code do I place this?

Comment: either create a css file or put it in <style> tags. Please learn basic html and css first http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html

Answer (score 0):

CSS is the solution:

```
#screen
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#keypad button
{
    width: 165px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

In JsFiddle jou put it in CSS section, in the real website you put it in your .css file: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: just tried this, it works. how do I get the text to populate from the top of the box and then go onto next line when I get to the end on the line?

Comment: You might want to use use <textarea> for multiline input. For usage refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: Been reading that website, but still cant see how to use <textarea>

Comment: instead of <input type="text" id="screen" /> you use <textarea id="screen" />

Comment: Weird, that may be the jsfiddle issue.